# ncurses on windows, can't receive KEY_MOUSE

Tags: terminal, ncurses

This is my program. It doesn't detect KEY_MOUSE, but `'q'` quits just fine. `'5'` also quits, both on keyboard and on numpad.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();

    // noecho();
    cbreak();
    // raw();

    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    mousemask( ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS, NULL);


    move(10,30);
    printw("Hello ncurses!\n");
    refresh();

    while(true) {
        int c = getch();
        // int c = wgetch(stdscr);
        if (c == 'q') break;
        if (c == '5') break;
        if (c == KEY_MOUSE) break;
    }

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if the problem is in the program, or in my enviroment. I used `msys2` to compile it on windows. Also I have `clink` installed, just to make working with `cmd.exe` less painfull.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you set your `$TERM` to something with a terminal description which does not support *mouse*, e.g., **`linux`** or **`vt100`**.  The console window for msys2 is mintty, which is based on PuTTY.